# Extracting text from an XML file based on an element's value?

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing

I have a simple XML file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<devices>

<device>
<name>Inside</name>
<value>67.662498</value>
</device>

<device>
<name>Outside</name>
<value>69.124992</value>
</device>

</devices>
```

I want to extract the temperature (value) for "Outside" using JavaScript.  Here is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","data.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

document.getElementById("name").innerHTML=
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
document.getElementById("value").innerHTML=
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("value")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
</script>
```

When I run this inside an HTML file, it pulls the name "Inside" and its temperature value and not the Outside temperature value.  I just want to be able to run this and have "69.124992" show up as the value.  What do I need to add to parse this file so it looks only for the device with the name "Outside"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current implementation is just getting the first occurrence of name and value and displaying the value, Instead why not just loop

```
var names = xml.getElementsByTagName('name');
for (var iDx = 0; iDx < names.length; iDx++) {
     if (names[iDx].childNodes[0].nodeValue == 'Outside') {
         jQuery('#name').text(names[iDx].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
         jQuery('#value').text(xml.getElementsByTagName('value')[iDx].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
         break;
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mprabhat/6Yzez/1/)

Comment: But that would pull all names and values, and I really want this code to just pull one value based on the value of the "name" element.  In other words, I want this to display just the temperature for "Outside".

I'm also using this HTML code to display the value:
    <div>
    <b>Value:</b> <span id="value"></span><br />
    </div>

Comment: I solved my own problem by loading the value through a specific index number.  I used the following: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_index