# Pull Data from an xml file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

Somewhat new to XML, but s there a way to pull info from an xml file based on the country and have it displayed in a div?

Ex. I just want data from the  element containing Europe, when the Europe btn/link is clicked then append into the global DIV.

```
<div>
    <div class="btn_all">
        <a href='#' value="Global" class="btn_globalImg"></a>
        <a href='#' value="Regional" class="btn_regionalImg"></a>
        <a href='#' value="Country" class="btn_countriesImg"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="btn_regions">
        <a href='#' value="Africa" class="btn_africaImg"></a>
        <a href='#' value="Asia" class="btn_asiaImg"></a>
        <a href='#' value="Europe" class="btn_eurImg"></a>
        <a href='#' value="Latin America" class="btn_latinImg"></a>
        <a href='#' value="North America" class="btn_northImg"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="btn_countries">
        <a href='#' value="Africa" class="btn_africaImg"></a>
        <a href='#' value="Asia" class="btn_asiaImg"></a>
        <a href='#' value="Europe" class="btn_eurImg"></a>
        <a href='#' value="Latin America" class="btn_latinImg"></a>
        <a href='#' value="North America" class="btn_northImg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="global"></div>
</div>

    <script>
        function ResetandSet(set){
            $('.btn_regions, .btn_countries').hide(); //hide regions submenu
            $('#global').html(""); //clear #global
            set=="global" ? $('.btn_globalImg').addClass('active'):$('.btn_globalImg').removeClass('active');
            set=="region" ? $('.btn_regionalImg').addClass('active'):$('.btn_regionalImg').removeClass('active');
            set=="country" ? $('.btn_countriesImg').addClass('active'):$('.btn_countriesImg').removeClass('active');
        }

    function loadXML(that) {
        var Step1 = $('.btn_all').find('.active').attr("value");
        var Step2 = $(that).attr("value");
        var cty_count="";

        $.get('inc/BestEmployers.xml', function(d){
            $(d).find('company').filter(function(){
                return Step1 == "Global" ? $(this).find("category").text() == Step1 : $(this).find("category").text() == Step1 && $(this).find("region").text() == Step2;
    //sort by
            }).each(function(){
                var name = $(this).attr("name");
                var category = $(this).find('category').text();
                var region = $(this).find('region').text();
                var country = $(this).find('country').text();
                var year = $(this).find('year').text();
                var employee = $(this).find('employee').text();
                var industry = $(this).find('industry').text();
                var url = $(this).find('url').text();
                var logo = $(this).find('logo').text();
                var quote = $(this).find('quote').text();
                var title = $(this).find('title').text();

                if (Step1 == "Global")
                    makeGlobal(name, category, region, country, year, employee, industry, url, logo, quote, title);
                else if (Step1 == "Regional") 
                    makeRegional(name, category, region, country, year, employee, industry, url, logo, quote, title);
                else if (Step1 == "Country") {
                    if (cty_count=="")
                        $('#global').append("<div class='header'><div>Company</div><div>Industry</div><div>Website</div><div>No. of Employees</div></div>");
                    if (cty_count != country) {
                        $('#global').append("<div class='subheader'>" + country + "</div>");
                        cty_count = country;
                    }
                    makeCountry(name, category, region, country, year, employee, industry, url, logo, quote, title);
                }
            });
        });
    }


    function makeGlobal(name, category, region, country, year, employee, industry, url, logo, quote, title){
        var html = '';
        html += "<div class='global'>";
            if(logo) {html += "<div><img src='images/" + logo + "' width='100px' height='100px'/></div>"}
            html += "<div>"
                if(name) {html += "<div class='company'>" + name + "</div>"}
                if(category) {html += "<div class='desc'>Certified Best Employer - " + category + " " + year+ "</div>"}
                if(employee) {html += "<div class='employee'>No of employees: " + employee + "<div>"}
                if(industry) {html += "<div class='industry'>Industry: " + industry + "</div>"}
                if(quote) {html += "<div class='quote'>" + quote + "</div>"}
                if(title) {html += "<div class='title'>From: " + title + "<div>"}
                if(url) {html += "<div class='more'><a href='" + url + "' target='_blank'>" + url + "</a></div>"}
            html += "</div>"
        html += "</div><br/>";
        $('#global').append($(html)); 
    }

    function makeRegional(name, category, region, country, year, employee, industry, url, logo, quote, title){
        var html = '';
            html += "<div class='regional'>";
            if(logo) {html += "<div><img src='images/" + logo + "' width='100px' height='100px'/></div>"}
            html += "<div>"
            if(name) {html += "<div class='company'>" + name + "</div>"}
            if(region) {html += "<div class='desc'>Certified Best Employer - " + region + " " + year+ "</div>"}
            if(employee) {html += "<div class='employee'>No of employees: " + employee + "<div>"}
            if(industry) {html += "<div class='industry'>Industry: " + industry + "</div>"}
            if(url) {html += "<div class='more'><a href='" + url + "' target='_blank'>" + url + "</a></div>"}
            html += "</div>"
            html += "</div><br/>";

        $('#global').append($(html)); 
    }
    function makeCountry(name, category, region, country, year, employee, industry, url, logo, quote, title){
        var html = '';
            html += "<div class='country'>";
            html += "<div class='name'>" + name + "</div>";
            html += "<div class='industry'>" + industry + "</div>";
            html += "<div class='website'><a href='" + url + "' target='_blank'>" + url + "</a></div>";
            html += "<div class='employee'>" + employee + "</div>";
        $('#global').append($(html)); 
    }


    /* Second Level Buttons */
        $('.btn_africaImg, .btn_asiaImg, .btn_eurImg, .btn_latinImg, .btn_northImg').click(function(){
            $('#global').html(""); //clear #global
            $('.btn_regions a, .btn_countries a').each(function( index ) { $(this).removeClass('active') });
            $(this).addClass('active')
            loadXML(this);

            $xml.find('country').each(function () {
        $(this).find("whatever you want").text()
    });
        }); 
    /* End Second Level Buttons */

    /* Top Level Buttons */
        $('.btn_regionalImg').click(function() {
            ResetandSet("region");
            $('.btn_regions').show(); //hide regions submenu
        });

        $('.btn_countriesImg').click(function() {
            ResetandSet("country");
            $('.btn_countries').show(); //hide regions submenu
        });
        $('.btn_globalImg').click(function() {
            ResetandSet("global");
            loadXML(this);
        });
    /* End Top Level Buttons */
    </script>

    /*  XML file */     
        <script type="text/xml" id="xmlData">
        <companies>
        <country>Europe<country>
            <company name="1" imageurl="logo">
            <certification> Certified Best Employer </certification>
            <employee> 5,0000 </employee>
            <industry> Risk Services </industry>
            <html_url> http://www.google.com </html_url>
            </company>
        <country>Europe<country>
            <company name="2" imageurl="logo">
            <certification> Certified Best Employer </certification>
            <employee> 5,0000 </employee>
            <industry> Risk Services </industry>
            <html_url> http://www.google.com </html_url>
            </company>
        <country>Asia<country>
            <company name="3" imageurl="logo">
            <certification> Certified Best Employer </certification>
            <employee> 5,0000 </employee>
            <industry> Risk Services </industry>
            <html_url> http://www.google.com </html_url>
            </company>
        </companies>
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to do this is to use some AJAX. First call a javascript function in your html div/body, or wherever.  In your javascript you can call your xml file and then do something like:

```
$xml.find('country').each(function () {
    $(this).find("whatever you want").text()
});
```

set your div with an id and then append the $(this) to the id

$(this).find("industry").text().appendTo('#divID')

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try. So If I wanted it to grab <country>Europe</country from XML depending on the value="Europe" link (above). How would I go about doing this?

Comment: you probably already figure it out but you would just replace country with companies and industry with country. If you want to see if it equals to Europe then you can go $(this).find("industry").text()="Europe"

Answer (score 0):

This example uses LINQ To XML to filter based on element value:

http://csharp-guide.blogspot.com/2012/06/linq-to-xml-filter-on-element-values.html

Once you get your query variable populated, you parse through it via whatever front-end construction process you are using (HTML Helpers in MVC app, ASP.Net server side objects, or a foreach loop on the result from a AJAX/JQuery call to generate HTML).

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a similiar questions and answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953642/extracting-text-from-an-xml-file-based-on-an-elements-value)

You'd need to rework the JS but you'd be able to easily target when the country node equals Europe, loop through with nextSibling(), build out your content and inject into a div.